# obtain force lock on file using java used by other process in windows

Tags: java, apache-commons, r.java-file

**I wanted to Override a file which is used by other process in windows machine using Java Program**,
 for which I want obtain force lock on file , please guide me how can I achieve.

I am using `org.apache.commons.io.monitor.FileAlterationObserver` to check whether file is changed or not if changed i want to override dest file with src file.

I tried both code snippets I am getting below exception.

#### Exception :

`The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)`

#### Code Snippet1

```
FileAlterationObserver observer = new FileAlterationObserver(folderToObserve);
observer.addListener(new FileAlterationListener() {
@Override
public void onFileChange(File file) {
System.out.println("File changed , file.getAbsolutePath() : "+file.getAbsolutePath());
file.delete();
try {
FileUtils.copyFile(srcFile, file);
//checkAndUpdateFile(srcFile, file);
} catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println("Error In overriding  file");
e.printStackTrace();
}
        }
```

#### Code Snippet2

```
private static void checkAndUpdateFile(File src, File dest) throws IOException {
      FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
      FileChannel srcChannel = in.getChannel();
      FileChannel destChannel = null;
      FileLock destLock = null;

      try {
        if (!dest.exists()) {
          final RandomAccessFile destFile = new RandomAccessFile(dest, "rw");
          destChannel = destFile.getChannel();
          destLock = destChannel.lock();
          copyFileChannels(srcChannel, destChannel);
          dest.setLastModified(src.lastModified());
        } else {
          final RandomAccessFile destFile = new RandomAccessFile(dest, "rw");
          destChannel = destFile.getChannel();
          destLock = destChannel.lock();
          if (!compareFileChannels(srcChannel, destChannel)) {
            copyFileChannels(srcChannel, destChannel);
            dest.setLastModified(src.lastModified());
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: I would say in general, it would be better to notify the user that an error occurred and that they need to close it in whatever application is holding the lock. Granted, you can't know that and the user would have to figure it out, but forcibly overwriting the file is very heavy handed. You don't know the effects of doing so.

Comment: I am not entirely sure if windows will allow you to delete/modify a locked file for reasons of data inconsistency. From what i have seen, this looks like an impossible task (at least not without killing the process which has the file lock).

Comment: Than you for the reply, I will check the option, but is there any way i can obtain force lock on files used by other process without killing the process.

Comment: I would hope not. Forcibly stealing a file lock from another application could leave the file corrupted if it's still writing.